# Video shifts to left on clicking the button to play it

Tags: jquery, css

When I click on the link to play the video, it shifts to the left of the page.The link is in the center of the page and I want the video to also open in the center of the page.  Instead, it opens on the left side of the page.The layer used Sublime HTML5 video player

html code

```
<div id="demo">
<table>
 <tr>   
<td><a href='#' id='start_video1' class='custom_start_view'><h3>Watch Demo</h3> </td>
<td><img src="assets/images/logo.png" width="50" height="50"/> </td>
</tr>
</a>
<video  id='video1' data-autoplay='true' poster='assets/images/logo.png' width='432' height='243' preload='none' style='display:none;'>
  <source src='assets/DreamItReelExplainerVideo.mp4' />
  <source src='assets/DreamItReelExplainerVideo.webm' data-quality='hd' />
  </video>
</table>
</div>
```

js code

Comment: Without seeing more (CSS/JS) it appears as though you have a hidden video container without anything making it centered. If you add `position:relative; margin: 0 auto;` to the CSS for the video container it will center the video container within it's offset parent (the ancestor element that dictates it's location). Again, without more info I can't be sure how this will work within your video framework.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your CSS code as well?

I strongly suspect you have different floats on the two elements, or possibly different margins.

Are you using JS to hide the image?

Check to make sure your float and margin settings are identical for the cover image and video.  Hope this helps!

(Right now you only have HTML posted, but you hint at JS towards the end of your post, try posting the CSS and any JS that affects the video or cover image)

Comment: Normally this type of answer would be posted as a comment until the OP actually adds the things you ask for.